# How to prevent markers from being drag while allowing draggable directions/routes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, draggable

Example code:
http://jsbin.com/ifaveq/2/edit#preview

I'm trying to get draggable routes with "non-draggble" markers but it seems once routes are declared "draggable" then the markers are automatically draggable and can't be marked as non-draggable.

Is this correct?